# Averaging elevation for fishnet points in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, elevation, vector-grid

[image]

I have a problem with adding average elevations for fishnet points. First of all I surveyed an area boundary of 16km2 using total stations. I got nearly 800 points to finish the boundary in this way. I have created fishnet points with the total station extent points as the limit for fishnet points.

I want to add averaging elevations for the the fishnet points with that total station points as base points. Both are in shapefile, so am not looking for suggestions involving raster processes.

There are 3000 fishnet points. Without any idea I am adding elevations for those 3000 points by averaging using calculator.

Comment: I think you may need to add a picture to your question to explain what you are trying to do.  I suspect that using Intersect (or Spatial Join) followed by Summary Statistics and Join Field *may* be what you need, but it is hard to tell.

Comment: Here I added the screenshot.That black points have elevation value.I want to add the elevation values for those green points(fishnet points),with black  points elevation as reference for averaging.now tell me the idea PolyGeo.

Comment: I think you need to create a surface using either 3D or Spatial Analyst.

Comment: I don't get to u plz explain the methods

Comment: I'm not licensed for 3D or Spatial Analyst so I'm not a potential answerer of your question.